# Pass a variable into string in VF page

Tags: string, salesforce

I have a string like this:

> This is {0}

I want to pass a variable into that position.

It's easily in Apex class but I dont know how to do this in VF page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Custom Label: In this case the custom label has to be defined first

   {!$Label.LabelName}
2. public String myString {get; set;} // in Controller class. You can set this String e.g. in the constructor

   {!myString}  // on VF-Page

Comment: Thank for response. I know this way, but with my bussines logic, I can't do this. I must to do this on VF page.

Comment: Can you please describe the use case a bit more? I'm not sure if i get u right